# Survival analysis with recurrent events: What is the difference between the "cluster" method from "lifelines" and the Andersen-Gill method?

Tags: survival, biostatistics, recurrent-events

Good afternoon,

I would like to better understand how the *cluster* method from the *lifelines* Python package differs from the Andersen-Gill method. Based on the definition of each (see below), the cluster method seems more conservative vs. the Andersen-Gill method, given the former does not treat recurrent events as independent. Am I thinking about these differences correctly?

Per the *lifelines* docs ([link](https://lifelines.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Survival%20Regression.html)):

> Another property your dataset may have is groups of related subjects. This could be caused by:
>
> - a single individual having multiple occurrences, and hence showing up in the dataset more than once.
> - subjects that share some common property, like members of the same family or being matched on propensity scores.

> We call these grouped subjects “clusters”, and assume they are designated by some column in the DataFrame (example below). When using cluster, the point estimates of the model don’t change, but the standard errors will increase.

By contrast, for the Andersen-Gill method ([link](https://bmcmedresmethodol.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/s12874-017-0462-x)):

> The Andersen-Gill model assumes independence between all observed event times irrespective whether these event times correspond to the same patient or to different patients.

Any help, insights, or suggestions would be extremely appreciated.